# Word for the fear of getting a haircut?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The other day I met someone who was scared of getting a haircut. I was trying to think of a word to describe, but I couldn't think of anything. I couldn't find anything online either, so I decided to ask here. **What is a word for the fear of getting a haircut?**

Comment: Are you talking about an *urgent haircut*?  A haircut on the stock market?  Assassination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual protocol for naming irrational fears is to add the Greek-derived suffix *-phobia* to the (classical) Greek word for what is feared. Classical Greek for haircut is [κουρά](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dkoura%2F), so with the usual Latinization we would get *curaphobia.* Unfortunately that form would appear to have been applied to a fear of paperwork by Urban Dictionary and its ilk. *Tonsurephobia* [has been suggested](http://www.hairfinder.com/info/haircutphobias.htm), and attributed to “experts”; it combines a Latin term with the Greek suffix, which some regard as barbarous. Neither word is in the OED.

Comment: Here's another site with an article entitled: [Help With Tonsurephobia](http://www.thriftyfun.com/Help-With-Tonsurephobia-Fear-of-Hair-Cuts.html)

Answer (score 0):

Fear of Getting a haircut is [Tonsurephobia](http://www.fearof.net/fear-of-getting-a-haircut-phobia-tonsurephobia/).

> Tonsurephobia is the fear of getting a haircut. The word Tonsurephobia
>   is derived from Greek words 'Tonsure' meaning ' to cut' and 'Phobos'
>   meaning 'deep dread or aversion'.

[Fearof.net]

Comment: What is the link for "haircut" for? Please don't link anything that is not related with your answer. [If you use direct quotations, always put them in quotation marks or in a quotation block.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/9602/what-is-plagiarism-how-do-i-avoid-it-how-do-i-address-it-when-i-see-it)

Answer (score -1):

Smart me went to google translate to get the Greek word for *haircut*, which turned out to be κούρεμα (kourema).

Thus *kouremaphobia*.

And *kourema mania* should be haircut mania. Whereas, *kouremaphilia* would be love for haircuts.

And I further found that *kouremata* is various ways to cut and style your hair.

Would *kourematomania* be a situation where hair-styling is an obsession?

And since *koureas* equals barber, then the words koureasphobia, koureasphobic, koureasmania, koureasmanic, koureasphilia, koureasphilic, carry meanings respective to their suffixes.

Comment: Indeed κούρεμα is *Modern* Greek for *haircut,* including the kind imposed on holders of Greek bonds in recent years. But for purposes of coinage in English, tradition favors classical Ionic dialect (and not classical Attic, where the two differ, as witness *thalassemia,* not *thalattemia,* for the Mediterranean version of sickle-cell anemia).

Comment: The only ionic bond I was schooled in is between atoms or molecules. Just kiddin.